# Return statement not working, with document.write

Tags: javascript, return

why doesn't `document.write(added);` work?

```
function first(){
    var now = new Date();
    var first=Math.round(now.getMilliseconds()/20);
    var second=Math.round(now.getMilliseconds()/30);
    var added=first+second;
    return added;
}
first();
document.write(added);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript has function scoping, which means that any variables declared in a function can't be accessed outside of that function. `return added` returns the *value* of added, not the variable `added` itself. If you want to use that value, you need to put it in a variable that was declared outside the function:

```
function first(){
    var now = new Date();
    var first=Math.round(now.getMilliseconds()/20);
    var second=Math.round(now.getMilliseconds()/30);
    var added=first+second;
    return added;
}
var firstResult = first();
document.write(firstResult);
```

More advanced, but related: [Types of Javascript Variable Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Answer (score 0):

because `added` is not a global variable, hence it is out of scope when you  call document.write.

You need to save the returned value in a variable in the same scope in which you call document.write, i.e. global scope in this case.
Correct code would be :

```
function first(){
var now = new Date();
var first=Math.round(now.getMilliseconds()/20);
var second=Math.round(now.getMilliseconds()/30);
var added=first+second;
return added;
}
var returnValue = first(); // store returned 'added' in returnValue
document.write(returnValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `scope issue` has already been pointed, I'm just gonna add another way to get result printed

```
document.write(first());
```